# Combo Box selecting multiple items

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Can someone explain this Behaviour?

[image]

---

Not only Does `MouseOver` Highlight multiple items(Not Intended), but when i `Select` the item (That the mouse is over) The Code goes to Selection_Changed event which changes the picture on the right of it (as intended) but While loading the picture, an error message appears that says that there's invalid characters in the path.

---

```
BD.Shape xShape = new BD.Shape();
comboBoxShapes.ItemsSource = xShape.GetListOfShapes();
```

---

```
 public List<String> GetListOfShapes()
    {
        List<String> iList = new List<String>();
        try
        {
            GetConnectionString iGet = new GetConnectionString();
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection iConnect = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            iConnect.ConnectionString = iGet.ConnectionString();
            iConnect.Open();
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand iCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
            iCommand.Connection = iConnect;
            iCommand.CommandText = "Select ShapeName from Shapes ";
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader iRead = iCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (iRead.Read())
            {
                Shape iShape = new Shape();
                iShape.ShapeName = iRead["ShapeName"].ToString();
                iList.Add(iShape.ShapeName);
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Someone better call batman or something `\\(^_^)_/`");
        }
        return iList;
    }
```

[image]

---

Please note that if i select anything else with a dash `-` in it it only selects one item. There are no hidden / invalid characters....

Comment: Please explain what the "it" you keep speaking of is. ("It" runs code ... "it" says ... "it" only selects one item ...)

Comment: Then update the question rather than assuming.  What is the selection mode of the combobox?  What is the sample at the bottom?

Comment: Is the Selection mode set to dropdownlist?

Comment: @JustinKirk: Your mouse can run code when you hover it over a list view item? Your mouse can "say that there's invalid characters in the path"? That's one amazing rodent. Are the screenshots from a program you wrote, or from a program someone else wrote that you want to be able to do the same as? Are you attempting to prevent it (whatever "it" is) "from run[nig] code to fill and image box that's beside it" (whatever _that_ "it" is). Is that code something you wrote (and it's being run too often? or you need your code to detect that "it" runs it and then do nothing?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there is not a new line character in the data?

Debug a count of items in that list.

```
 string same = "same" + Environment.NewLine + "next Line";
 List<string> lstring = new List<string> { "one", "two - a", "two - b", "three", "three", same, same };
 cb1.ItemsSource = lstring;
```

This has the select behavior you describe.

Comment: can new line only be generated by \n ?

Comment: LOL, i've been looking at the code for an error, In the access database  it shows that sonora is 1 line(as shown in the screenshot), but if i highlight it and pull down it reveals sedona below it, i just couldn't see it because of the height of the row -_-